# Apple Pay - what's the new limit?

Tags: apple-pay

Apple Pay increased the transaction limits recently.
In the UK it used to be £30, but is now 'higher' - without a limit being mentioned in Apple's [Cashless made effortless](https://www.apple.com/uk/apple-pay/) page [UK link].

Though it's not usable everywhere - stores must update their equipment to use it apparently - I've paid for the weekly shopping at Sainsbury's for a bill of over £100, which I was slightly wary it may have rejected - but it didn't.

Is there a published limit anywhere, or is it up to your bank/card supplier to enforce their own transaction limit?

Answer (score 2):

There's no limitation on Apple Pay itself. The limitation comes from the terminal that the store uses.

If you have a terminal that supports contactless cards and nothing else the limit is £30 per purchase, £100 per day, just as for a contactless card. The limit is low to avoid someone stealing your card and going on a shopping spree. And the stupid terminal doesn't realise that you have an iPhone that is much better protected than your card.

If you have a terminal that recognises Apple Pay, that terminal would know that you are really there with your phone in your hand, with the user of the phone pressing a button, so the transaction is much safer and the limit is much higher. What the actual limit is will depend on your bank.

Note: The difference isn't that one is unsafe and one is safe, the difference is that in the first case the terminal *doesn't know* it's safe, and in the second case it knows.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but do you have any citations? Empirically I have found it's >100, but it seems no-one is actually publishing this data anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There are published limits [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207435) which vary by country.

For the United Kingdom the limits varies by issuer as follows:

> #### United Kingdom
>
> You might not be able to use Apple Pay for purchases over 30 GBP.

Comment: "Might not" depends on the store's agreement with Apple & the age of their hardware. It doesn't give any definitive figures, You can spend up to £30 pretty much anywhere in the country & it's rare now to find anywhere that doesn't accept contactless. For the big players - Asda, old hardware, old £30 limit. Sainsbury's, new hardware, empirically tested to >£100. So, that link tells me nothing I didn't already know & in fact less than I **do** already know.